# How to wrap the subject line in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

In vertical view, for sake of readability, I'd like to wrap the subject line.

Instead of having:

```
Jane Doo | A very long ... | 6/6/2015
```

I'd like to read

```
Jane Doo | A very long     | 6/6/2015
         | subject wrapped |
```

How to do this?

Comment: Reference bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213945